# Android + Google Drive = Error downloading file?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

### Context

I'm downloading a file off Google Drive through their Android SDK. In most cases it works just fine, but I do have a few instances where it simply cannot be downloaded - no specific reason given other than that.

### **This is the crash log:**

Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldnt get drive contents: Status{statusCode=Error downloading file, resolution=null}

### And this is the actual code

```
public DriveContents getDriveContents(DriveId driveId, int mode) {
    final DriveFile theFile = driveId.asDriveFile();
    final DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result =
            theFile.open(mClient, mode, null).await();
    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        final String status = result.getStatus().toString();
        Crashlytics.logException(new RuntimeException("Couldnt get drive contents: " + status));
    }
    return result.getDriveContents();
}
```

- The code is **only** ever executed when the user has signed in (hence the app has permissions).
- It is extremely rare, but it does happen from time to time, and considering that this is the users data backup; I want it working 100%.

### **Why is this happening?** **How can I fix it?**

Comment: Does it succeed if you retry download of the same file?

Comment: @Anatoli I dont have hands on with this so I cant really try that -- Its a few of my apps users seeing it.

Comment: it might be network failures, or something of that sort. Maybe you can retry the download and log transient vs. permanent failures.

Comment: @Anatoli I will get some more insights on the subject in a few days time. Although I can say that there is an error message for network problems, and this one is different from it.

Comment: What's the size of the file? Could it be that the internet connection broke during this rare occasions?

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Comment: @noogui It still happens and I never have any idea why. But I did implement a smart backoff system that attempts the sync later on, and so far so good.

Comment: well good job on the workaround then.

Comment: @noogui Thanks, if youre interested in a similar approach you can look into the Evernote-Job library which lets you setup jobs to be performed under certain circumstances, as well as expontential backoff logic.

Comment: Thanks will take a look at Evernote-Job library :)